CSS How to set sticky for element if parent has overflow-x: auto?
I can't find a solution for my problem.
I have a table, and I need to add horizontal scroll (overflow-x: auto) and sticky header of the table.
I try to add one more wrapper with different positions - but it isn't works.
I need to sticky header in respect of vertical scrolling
How I can do that?
https://codepen.io/ilyakorn/pen/zYQzaar


.main {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 30;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  padding: 10px;
}
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title 1</th>
        <th>Title 2</th>
        <th>Title 3</th>
        <th>Title 4</th>
        <th>Title 5</th>
        <th>Title 6</th>
        <th>Title 7</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td>Td1</td>
        <td>Td2</td>
        <td>Td3</td>
        <td>Td4</td>
        <td>Td5</td>
        <td>Td6</td>
        <td>Td7</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>




The horizontal scrollbar for the table is working. It's just hidden by the main div which have overflow-y:auto being set. You can see it if you scroll all the way down.
If what you are trying to do is to make the vertical scroll bar for scrolling the table body appear on the main div while showing the table's horizontal scrollbar without scrolling down, you need to double check the design. It is not possible and visually doesn't makes sense.
Otherwise, if overflow-y:auto is solely for vertically scrolling the content of the table (instead of the content for main), move overflow-y:auto from main down to wrapper and set height:100% on it. This won't break the sticky header.
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}



.main {
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 30;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid brown;
  padding: 10px;
}
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Title 1</th>
          <th>Title 2</th>
          <th>Title 3</th>
          <th>Title 4</th>
          <th>Title 5</th>
          <th>Title 6</th>
          <th>Title 7</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Td1</td>
          <td>Td2</td>
          <td>Td3</td>
          <td>Td4</td>
          <td>Td5</td>
          <td>Td6</td>
          <td>Td7</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>



